# Distance Between Two DFs With A Few Variables

Tags: python, dataframe, coordinates, distance, geopy

I'd like some help with a kind of complex situation. I'll try to be very objective and thanks in advance:

I have two dataframes. 1) **df** has a list of a few thousand coordinates of services done on the field, 2) **dfbase** has a few coordinates, for physical bases where each person starts their services from.

I need to calculate the distance between each base in **dfbase** to the respective coordinate in **df**.

The thing is, they must be in the same area code (common column ROTA) which consists into breaking an ZCGUNLEIT to a substring, 3, 3.

[image: dfbase]

[image: df]

However, not every ROTA has a physical base. For example, ROTA 071 has no base, but 072 has. So if a ROTA doesn't have a base, the distance should be calculated for this coordinate to the next ROTA, in this case 072.

I'm using GEOPY to do that, but could not understand how to write. My last try was to merge both dataframes into **df2** so that every coordinate in **df** has a either a 0.0 matching (for cases which that route doesn't have a coordinate) or a respective base with coordinates, as below:

[image]

This was my last try, which resulted in the error: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds:

```
dist=[0]
for i in range(1,len(df2)):
    if df2.ROTA.iloc[i]==df.ROTA.iloc[i]:
      dist.append(geopy.distance.geodesic((df2.LATITUDE.iloc[i],df2.LONGITUDE.iloc[i]),(df2.Latitude.iloc[i],df2.Longitude.iloc[i])).km)
    elif df2.ROTA.iloc[i] == df2.ROTA.iloc[i+1]:
      dist.append(geopy.distance.geodesic((df2.LATITUDE.iloc[i],df2.LONGITUDE.iloc[i]),(df2.Latitude.iloc[i],df2.Longitude.iloc[i])).km)
    else: dist.append(0)

df2['DIST']=dist
```

Comment: I would join the data frame and compute the distances directly without any loops

Comment: This question is currently pretty complex, especially since we don't have access to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/hlep/minimal-reproducible-example).  You are more likely to receive useful advice if you break it down and focus your question(s) on individual parts that you are stuck on.  I agree that you should try to join the dataframes without loops.  Consider using the pandas [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) function to merge on nearest ROTA values.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know _asof. Will give it a try and come back. THanks.